# Is there a Ruby equivalent to the "fuser" command?

Tags: ruby, unix

I'd like to check which processes currently have an open descriptor to a file. I can do this with the "fuser" command; is there a method in the Ruby standard library which behaves similarly?

Comment: You can always run it from the shell, if needed, using `Open3.capture3` to get the output...

Comment: Yup, I'll do that if there doesn't seem to be a nicer way. :)

Comment: I don't think that there's something like that, you will have to roll your own, e.g. `\`fuser #{filename}\`.split.map(&:to_i)`

Comment: This is a very lowlevel functionality. I don't think that ruby provides a similar functionality, especially as it is probably pretty hard to do that on windoo$